# No helm package when list packages in Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

Helm Manual instruction clearly says that to install helm - the M+x list-packages menu should contain one. There isn't one - What to do?

Comment: Make sure you have [melpa](https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa#usage) enabled in your `package-archives` then run `package-refresh-contents`.

Comment: there is no command package-archives

Comment: Yeah, `package-archives` is a variable. If you follow Carl's link you'll see some instructions for setting up melpa.

PS: congrats on asking Emacs question #13333.

Comment: well, if something has very low quality documentation - people will ask stupid questions many times